# Use Swift to Decode Realtime Database Response

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, codable

I am trying to decode a firebase realtime database response but running into a decoding error, I do not think it's my structs that are the problem but I do not know where I am going wrong, what am I doing wrong?

The issue now seems to be with `PromoCodeUsed` Being a dictionary instead of an array

```
ERROR HERE: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "usedBy", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Code:

```
func getPromoCodeInfo(handler: @escaping (PromoCode?) -> ()) {
        guard let userid = AuthService.shared.userID else { return }
        promoCodes.queryOrdered(byChild: "owner").queryEqual(toValue: userid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            
            
            for child in snapshot.children {
                guard let snap = child as? DataSnapshot else { return }
                guard let value = snap.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: [])
                    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(PromoCode.self, from: jsonData)
                    handler(decoded)
                } catch {
                    print("ERROR HERE: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

dataModel

```
struct PromoCode: Codable {
    var active: Int
    var amount: Int?
    var code: String
    var percent: Int?
    var owner: Int?
    var usedBy: [PromoCodeUsed]?
}

struct PromoCodeUsed: Codable {
    var amount: Int
    var date: String
    var paid: Int
    var userid: Int
}
```

Data

```
{
  "active": 1,
  "code": "FELLA",
  "owner": 33206,
  "percent": 50,
  "usedBy": {
    "-N5lHtnKtAiBWrQMxW0a": {
      "amount": 1000,
      "date": "2022-06-29 21:08:51 +0000",
      "paid": false,
      "userid": 33206
    },
    "-N6L0vybeecuu175FV-4": {
      "amount": 5000,
      "date": "2022-07-07 00:20:41 +0000",
      "paid": false,
      "userid": 33206
    },
    "-N6L0w5WVS6mkVGrfJMW": {
      "amount": 5000,
      "date": "2022-07-07 00:20:41 +0000",
      "paid": false,
      "userid": 33206
    },
    "-N6L190TsMr6OJAXod1G": {
      "amount": 1000,
      "date": "2022-07-07 00:21:38 +0000",
      "paid": false,
      "userid": 33206
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code needs to handle this list, but fails to do so. The easiest way to handle the list is to [loop over the children of the snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%5bswift%5d%20loop%20over%20children) you get, so loop over `snapshot.children` and then convert each individual child snapshot to a `PromoCode` object.

Comment: I think that helped, but now I am getting a new decode error with ```[PromoCodeUsed]?``` Being a dictionary in the database, how can I fix that so it can be decoded as an array of that object type?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert on that part. It might be a good idea to post a new question, with just a single `PromoCode` in the database and code that tried to load just that.